# Library Title showing as "Error" when user doesn't have permissions

Tags: permissions

I have a customer site where, if the user doesn't have permissions to view the library, the title shows "Error" rather than the name of the library but denying permissions when clicked.

[image]

Any guidance on how to resolve this display as the customer wants either the library name displayed (but when clicked an "access denied" error comes up) or they want the library not to display at all.

UPDATE: As requested, a larger image of the issue:

[image]

Comment: You'll need to elaborate on what is happening on your site. How is that title displayed there?

Comment: Updated as requested with a larger image.

Comment: If you append `?contents=1` to the url: What is shown on the page?